# How to return a variable in java constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I use constructor Calcu_weight to assign values to "weight" and "sumweight". The problem is once I call the Calcu_weight, it assign values to weight and sumweight, but when I call it again, weight and sumweight are already assigned, which influence the second constructor.
I wonder how can I use the constructor "Calcul_weight" a lot of times, and return those two TreeMap variables, but the later ones will not influence previous ones.

```
public class Calcul_weight {

    private TreeMap<int[],Double> weight = new TreeMap<int[],Double>(new SerializableIntegerArrayKeyComparator());
    private TreeMap <Integer,Double> sumweight = new TreeMap <Integer, Double>();

    public Calcu_weight(int originID,int dest, Network network, Dijkstra dijkstra){
        // calculate weight for links. network and dijkstra are another two constructors
    }

    public TreeMap<int[],Double> getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
    public TreeMap<Integer,Double> getSumweight(){
        return sumweight;
}
```

Comment: You cannot invoke a constructor more than once on the same object, though one constructor can invoke other constructors of the same class, and ultimately a constructor of the superclass will be invoked.

Comment: There is no Calcu_weight constructor in the posted code. It doesn't compile. Constructors are used to initialize objects. Not to perform complex computations.

Comment: What do you mean with _network and dijkstra are another two constructors_?

Comment: Your class is named `Calcul_weight`, and it has a maybe-intended-to-be constructor wrongly named `Weight`.

Comment: I see no reason to think that the code you've presented behaves as you describe, to the extent I understand what you're describing.  If you want help, present a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Constructors don't return anything, @Oyebisi.

Comment: @09817167d, `Calcul_weight` doesn't conform to the Java naming conventions. You should avoid using mutable objects like `int[]` as keys into a `Map`. The arguments to the (misnamed) constructor `Weight` are not constructors but pointers to already-constructed objects.

Comment: @LewBloch upon further reading, I stand corrected.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors . html check it out, then run through the rest of the classes and objects trail. Then approach your problem again and you will have a better handle on it.

Comment: Btw you don't have a constructor declared. The constructor must be named the same as the class. Your method named `Weight` is not a constructor. It's just a regular method. So your premise is a bit off. The code you have as is shouldn't even compile as the method Weight does not have a return type specified.

Comment: @Irkwz Please do not make edits to post that edit out the problems that are being asked about. If you have solutions or major corrections, they belong in comments and answers (such as your current answer), not in edits.

Comment: I change it a little bit. Sorry for inconvenience. It should be Calcu_weight

Comment: I fixed the problem by clear those treemaps, and now it is working. I wonder whether this is the correct way to do.

Comment: @John Bollinger
I wonder the statement of question clear and valid now?
Though I fix the problem, I still want to know is there a way for a constructor to provide an output?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a **singleton** to hold `weight` and `sumweight` between different instantiations of the same `Calcul_weight`.

You must also rename the class `Weight` or rename the `Weight(...)` function in `Calcul_weight(...)` order to become a proper constructor).

Comment: Sorry @JasonC for my bad english, of course you are right about "at least"; I'll correct immediately.